Understanding alternate representations of summations: Why is $\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} i \ne \frac{1}{2}(n-1)n$
I’ve come across a summation expression and I’m a bit confused about it's correct form and value. Specifically, I’m trying to understand why the summation:
$$\sum_{i=n-1}^{1} i$$
Wolfram Alpha gives me this result Result in Wolfram Alpha :
$$-\frac{1}{2} (-3 + n) n$$
But I'm confused cause for me it's just the inverse sum of $$\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} {i}= \frac{n(n-1)}{2}$$ but then why don't they match?
Am I right in thinking about those sum as :
First one : $$n-1+n-2+ \dots + 1$$
and second one as :
$$1 + 2+ \dots + n-2+n-1$$

Maybe you can recheck what you wrote in wolfram alpha. The expression is negative for $n>3$.

You need to show us the code. Also, this is not a question for this platform

why isn't it a question for this platform ?

@BarthélémyCoquoz There is  https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/ where you can ask questions about the wolfram language.

Wolfram is treating the $n$ as negative to assert the order of summation.
So, $$\sum_{n-1}^1 i = 1-\sum_{1}^{|n|+1} i = 1-\frac{(|n|+1)(|n|+2)}{2} = -\frac{|n|(|n|+3)}{2}$$.
